# fltro de listagem em 2 tabelas MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Tenho 3 modelos: `Pessoa`, `Catequizando` e `Inscricao`. Pretendo fazer uma query que devolva o Nome da pessoa onde `CatequizandoID = PessoaID` que vai aparecer numa dropdown na view `CriarInscricao`

Tentei usar isto no controlador da Inscrição mas devolve-me sempre null:

```
public ActionResult CriarInscricao() 
{ 
    var queryCatequizandos = from p in db.Pessoa 
                             join c in db.Catequizando on p.PessoaID equals c.CatequizandoID 
                             select new { p.Nome, p.PessoaID }; 

    ViewBag.CatequizandoID = new SelectList(db.Pessoa, "PessoaID", "Nome");         
    return View(); 
}

namespace WebAppCatechesis2.Models {
    public partial class Pessoa {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public Pessoa()
        {
            // uma PESSOA pode ser referenciada como mais do que uma catequese
            // uma PESSOA pode ser referenciada como mais do que uma PARTICIPACAOEMEVENTOS
            //
            this.Catequese = new HashSet<Catequese>();
            this.ParticipacaoEmEventos = new HashSet<Participacao>();
            Pais = new HashSet<Catequizando>();
            Maes = new HashSet<Catequizando>();
            EncarregadosEducacao = new HashSet<Catequizando>();


        }
        //chave primaria
        [Key]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PessoaID { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o nome da Pessoa")]
        //[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "No minimo o nome da Pessoa tem que ter 3 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Campo Pessoa com um máximo de 60 caracteres")]
        //[RegularExpression("[A-Z][a-zãéêíúóá]+(( ){1,3}[A-Z][a-zãéêíúóá]+)*", ErrorMessage = "Deve escrever o nome da Pessoa, começando cada palavra por maiúscula, este campo não aceita digitos numéricos")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome da Pessoa")]
        public String Nome { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a Morada")]
        //[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "No minimo a morada tem que ter 3 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Morada com um maximo de 100 caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Morada")]
        public String Morada { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-zãéêíúóá]+$", ErrorMessage = "Este campo só aceita caracteres alfabéticos")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "No maximo a Localidade tem que ter 30 caracteres")]
        //[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "No minimo a Localidade tem que ter 3 caracteres")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a Localidade")]
        [Display(Name = "Localidade")]
        public String Localidade { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression("[0-9]{7}", ErrorMessage = "O Código Postal só aceita digitos numéricos. Deve escrever 7 digitos.")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o Código Postal")]
        [Display(Name = "Código Postal")]
        public String CodPostal { get; set; }


        //[RegularExpression("[0-9]{9}", ErrorMessage = "O contacto telefónico só aceita digitos numéricos. Deve escrever 9 digitos.")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o contacto telefónico")]
        [Display(Name = "Número de Telemóvel")]
        public String Telemovel { get; set; }


        //[RegularExpression(@"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z",
        //ErrorMessage = "Insira um endereço de email válido")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Email obrigatório")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha o género")]
        [UIHint("Genero")]
        public Boolean Genero { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-zãéêíúóá]+$", ErrorMessage = "Este campo só aceita caracteres alfabéticos")]
        //[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Naturalidade com minimo de 5 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Naturalidade com maximo de 30 caracteres")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a naturalidade")]
        [Display(Name = "Naturalidade")]
        public String Naturalidade { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-zãéêíúóá]+$", ErrorMessage = "Este campo só aceita caracteres alfabéticos")]
        //[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Nacionalidade com minimo de 5 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Nacionalidade de 30 caracteres")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a naturalidade")]
        [Display(Name = "Nacionalidade")]
        public String Nacionalidade { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression("[0-9]{8}", ErrorMessage = "O BI só aceita digitos numéricos. Deve escrever 8 digitos.")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o número do BI")]
        [Display(Name = "Nº BI")]
        public String BI { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression("[0-9]{9}", ErrorMessage = "O NIF só aceita digitos numéricos. Deve escrever 9 digitos.")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o número do NIF")]
        [Display(Name = "NIF")]
        public String NIF { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha o estado civil")]
        [Display(Name = "Estado Civil")]
        public String Estado_Civil { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-zãéêíúóá]+$", ErrorMessage = "Este campo só aceita caracteres alfabéticos")]
        //[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Profissão com minimo de 3 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Profissão de 30 caracteres")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a profissão")]
        [Display(Name = "Profissão")]
        public String Profissao { get; set; }


        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha o estado civil")]
        [Display(Name = "Habilitações Literárias")]
        public String Habilitacoes_Literarias { get; set; }


        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha a data de nascimento")]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        public String DataNascimento { get; set; }

        public String Foto { get; set; }

        //[MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Este campo só perminte um máximo de 500 caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Observações")]
        public virtual String Observacoes { get; set; }


        // Uma PESSOA pode ser um CATEQUISTA e um CATEQUIZANDO
        public virtual Catequista Catequista { get; set; }
        public virtual Catequizando Catequizando { get; set; }




        //lista as eventuais referencias a uma PESSOA como PAI 
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Catequizando> Pais { get; set; }

        //lista as eventuais referencas a uma PESSOA como MAE
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Catequizando> Maes { get; set; }

        //lista as eventuais referencas a uma PESSOA como Encarregado de educacao
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Catequizando> EncarregadosEducacao { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Catequese> Catequese { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Participacao> ParticipacaoEmEventos { get; set; }
    }
} 

namespace WebAppCatechesis2.Models {
    public partial class Catequizando {

        public Catequizando()
        {
            this.Avaliacao = new HashSet<Avaliacao>();
            this.Inscricao = new HashSet<Inscricao>();
            this.Eventos = new HashSet<Evento>();
        }

        //chave primária e forasteira
        [Key, ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
        public int CatequizandoID { get; set; }

        //[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo de 3 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 30 caracteres")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o nome da escola")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome Escola")]
        public String NomeEscola { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o ano escolar")]
        [Display(Name = "Ano Escolar")]
        public String AnoEscolar { get; set; }


        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a turma escolar")]
        [Display(Name = "Turma escolar")]
        public String TurmaEscolar { get; set; }

        //[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo de 3 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 30 caracteres")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha este campo")]
        [Display(Name = "Cédula Cristã")]
        public String CedulaCrista { get; set; }


        // FK para a tabela PESSOA a referenciar um PAI, MAR, ENC DE EDUCACAO.
        // preenchimento NÃO obrigatório
        public int? Pai { get; set; }
        public int? Mae { get; set; }
        public int? EncEducacao { get; set; }

        //referencia os dados particulares deste CATEQUIZANDO, descritos no obj PESSOA
        public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
        //referencia o obj PAI
        public virtual Pessoa MeuPai { get; set; }
        //referencia o obj MAE
        public virtual Pessoa MinhaMae { get; set; }
        //referencia o obj ENC DE EDUCACAO
        public virtual Pessoa MeuEncEducacao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Evento> Eventos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Avaliacao> Avaliacao { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Inscricao> Inscricao { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace WebAppCatechesis2.Models {
    public partial class Inscricao {
        public Inscricao()
        {
            this.Grupo = new HashSet<Grupo>();
        }
        //chave primária
        public int InscricaoID { get; set; }

        //chave forasteira

        //[MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 1 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 15 caracteres")] 
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o ano pastoral")]
        [Display(Name = "Ano Pastoral")]
        public String AnoPastoral { get; set; }

        //[MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 1 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 50 caracteres")]   
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o ano catequese")]
        //[Display(Name = "Ano Catequese")]
        public String AnoCatequese { get; set; }

        //[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 3 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 50 caracteres")]  
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira o horário preferencial")]
        [Display(Name = "Horário Preferencial")]
        public String Horario_Preferencial { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a data de inscrição")]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Inscrição")]
        public String Data_Inscricao { get; set; }

        //[MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 1 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 30 caracteres")]  
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Insira a taxa de isncrição")]
        [Display(Name = "Taxa de Inscrição")]
        public String Taxa_Inscricao { get; set; }

        //[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 5 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 30 caracteres")]  
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Seguro")]
        [Display(Name = "Seguro")]
        public String Seguro { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Pagamento")]
        [Display(Name = "Pago")]
        public Boolean Pago { get; set; }

        //[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Minimo de 3 caracteres")]
        //[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Máximo de 30 caracteres")] 
        [Display(Name = "Donativo")]
        public String Donativo { get; set; }

        //[MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Este campo só perminte um máximo de 500 caracteres")]
        public String Observacoes { get; set; }


        public int CatequizandoID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CatequizandoID")]
        public virtual Catequizando Catequizando { get; set; }

        //define a ligação a tabela Catequese 1:N
        public int CatequeseID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CatequeseID")]

        public virtual Catequese Catequese { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Grupo> Grupo { get; set; }
    }      
}
```

*View*:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatequizandoID, "Catequizando", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) 
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
        @Html.DropDownList("CatequizandoID", null, "--Escolha um Catequizando--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatequizandoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código do *Controller* na sua pergunta?

Comment: E a *View*? Como fica?

Answer (score 0):

WickedOne, eu tenho algumas estruturas como essa nas minhas aplicações. Você está tratando de uma View de Criação certo? Assim é relativamente simples pois apenas precisamos mostrar um nome para escolha e gravar a ID na base de dados. O select que você fez ali está retornando os dados na lista? Coloque o breakpoint no select para ver se a lista está retornando null antes ou se o problema é no selectlist, por exemplo:

Aqui:

```
var queryCatequizandos = from p in db.Pessoa 
join c in db.Catequizando on p.PessoaID equals c.CatequizandoID 
select new { p.Nome, p.PessoaID };
```

Na minha estrutura eu utilizo assim:

No Controller:

```
 var lista = db.Cliente.Where(c => c.Ativo == true).ToList();
    return query.ToList();

    ViewBag.Id_Cliente = new SelectList(lista, "Id", "Fantasia");
```

Na View:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdCliente, "Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   @Html.DropDownList("IdCliente", null, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdCliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Antes de saber o que está dando errado, precisamos saber se a sua lista está retornando null ou se o problema está sendo ir pra view. Abraços.

Comment: @WickedOne conseguiu testar a minha sugestão?